# Postgres, Local installed instance interfered with Docker instance

Tags: postgresql, docker

Windows 10-Pro. Have a local Postgres installed and working fine.

With it running, VSC terminal, `docker-compose up` the following ok:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:10.4.2
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - ./sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass1
      POSTGRES_DB: db
```

But **PSQL shell** always complain password authentication failed for user.

Stopping postgres service from Windows Services and `docker-compose up`, **PSQL shell** authentication and query ok. But VSC terminal keep complaining another thing:

```
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
DETAIL:  User "postgres" has no password assigned.
Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all all all md5"
```

How to stop the above error when docker container's instance is running? Also, possible to co-run both local and docker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you are enjoying you containers journey !

I tried to execute your docker-compose as it was but cannot fetch the postgres:10.4.2 image:

```
❯ docker-compose up
[+] Running 0/1
 ⠿ postgres Error                                                                                                           2.1s
Error response from daemon: manifest for postgres:10.4.2 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
```

so i decided to use postgres:14.2 instead. Since I dont have your sql script i'll comment out the volume section.

Here is how my docker-compose looks like:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.2
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    # volumes:
    #   - ./sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass1
      POSTGRES_DB: db
```

So, when a execute the compose I got this:

```
❯ docker-compose up -d
[+] Running 1/1
 ⠿ Container postgre-local-and-dockercompose-71984505-postgres-1  Started

❯ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS
         NAMES
4b90573f6108   postgres:14.2                        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   18 seconds ago   Up 15 seconds   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp      postgre-local-and-dockercompose-71984505-postgres-1
```

When i connect to the container with:

```
❯ docker exec -it  postgre-local-and-dockercompose-71984505-postgres-1 bash
root@4b90573f6108:/#
```

and execute this command to connect to your created DB and connect with the "pass1" password:

```
root@4b90573f6108:/# psql --username=$POSTGRES_USER -W --host=localhost --port=5432 --dbname=$POSTGRES_DB
Password:
psql (14.2 (Debian 14.2-1.pgdg110+1))
Type "help" for help.

db=#
```

everything is fine.

So I advise you to use the same postgres:14.2 image i tried with (patched with the last security issues) and do the same test.
If you want me to test exactly what you are doing just send your sql scripts.

To answer your second question, yes it is possible to co-run both local and docker postgres instances

you just have to port-forward the postgresql port of your container to another port like this:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.2
    ports:
      - '5433:5432'
    # volumes:
    #   - ./sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass1
      POSTGRES_DB: db
```

since there is no port conflict (your local db is running on 5432 and your docker db on 5433), everything will work fine (I will use dbeaver to try to connect ):

PERFECT !
[image]
[image]

Hope I answered your questions.

bguess.